# Data from HealthKit is initially missing, then comes in when I try again - how to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I have an iOS app that I'm developing in Swift, and as part of the app it gathers the step count for the current day.

The first time I run the app, the count is "0", but if I click a button in the interface to re-run this function that queries HK, then the correct number appears.

I am guessing this is because HK needs some time to gather the data, or something, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Maybe HK can fire an event when the data is ready, and then I can update the UI?

Here's the routine that gathers the data from HK. This function executes immediately when the app start (and it shows "0 steps today"), and then as I describe above, I can tap a button to execute the function again (and then I get the right number).

```
    func queryStepsSum() {
        // prepare HK for the data
        let endDate = NSDate()          // right now
        let startDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(0, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: endDate, options: NSCalendarOptions())
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, options: .None)
        let sumOption = HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum
        let statisticsSumQuery = HKStatisticsQuery( quantityType: self.stepsCount!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
                                                    options: sumOption)
        { [unowned self] (query, result, error) in
            if let sumQuantity = result?.sumQuantity() {
                self.numberOfSteps = Int(sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))
            }
        }

        // run the HK query
        self.healthStore?.executeQuery(statisticsSumQuery)

        // update the UI with the result
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.stepsLabel.text = "\(self.numberOfSteps) steps today";
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this method from core motion? queryStepCountStartingFrom

Comment: Yes-- but I've got everything working with HealthKit, and I'm also getting other data from HK so I'd like to keep it consistent in my code. Plus CoreMotion won't accept step data from other devices (like a Fitbit) so HK is a better choice for more compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't wait for the query to finish before displaying the result (the query happens asynchronously). You should update your UI from the query's result handler, like this:

```
    let statisticsSumQuery = HKStatisticsQuery( quantityType: self.stepsCount!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
                                                options: sumOption)
    { [unowned self] (query, result, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if let sumQuantity = result?.sumQuantity() {
                self.numberOfSteps = Int(sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))
                self.stepsLabel.text = "\(self.numberOfSteps) steps today";
            }
        }
    }
```

Also note that I've included a dispatch back to the main thread since the query results handler runs on a background thread and it's not safe to manipulate UI in that context.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you for both of the tips. I learned something here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your function in viewDidLoad? You might try calling it in viewDidAppear instead.
If that doesn't work maybe there is some sort of delegate method that can update you when the data is ready like you said. I've never worked with HealthKit but I'll check to see if I can find anything.

EDIT:
This might set the UI component off the background thread.
Try:

```
var numberOfSteps: Int! {
    didSet {
        self.stepsLabel.text = "\(self.numberOfSteps) steps today"
    }
}
```

That should get rid of the error that you're updating the UI on the background thread. Also make sure to remove your call in the closure that I told you to put.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried moving the function call to viewDidAppear() but no luck, same results.

Comment: I looked and there doesn't seem to be any sort of delegate. Have you tried setting stepsLabel.text inside the closure? Maybe calling it right after numberOfSteps would work.

Comment: This sorta works! For my widget view, there's a long lag time but it does update the number. But for the main app view, I get an error, "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release." --so hmm. Halfway there. ;-) Thank you!

Comment: That makes sense. I read that queries from HealthKit are called on a random background thread. I edited my answer above see if that gets rid of the error.